# I want to retrieve image from database and display it in JSP using <img> tag. I am using my sql

Tags: java, html, mysql, jsp, servlets

I want to retrieve image from database and display it in JSP using `img` tag. I am using mySql.

```
public class DisplayImage extends  HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        //PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
        String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demodb";;
        java.sql.Connection con=null;
        try{  
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            con=DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL,"root","0321");  
            Statement st1=con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs1 = st1.executeQuery("select photo from contacts where  contact_id='2'");
            String imgLen="";
            if(rs1.next()){
                imgLen = rs1.getString(1);
                System.out.println(imgLen.length());
            }  
            rs1 = st1.executeQuery("select photo from contacts where contact_id='2'");
            if(rs1.next()){
                int len = imgLen.length();
                byte [] rb = new byte[len];
                InputStream readImg = rs1.getBinaryStream(1);
                int index=readImg.read(rb, 0, len);  
                System.out.println("index"+index);
                st1.close();
                response.reset();
                response.setContentType("image/jpg");
                response.getOutputStream().write(rb,0,len);
                response.getOutputStream().flush();  
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This Code display image directly. But I want the path. So I can display it wherever I want. Are there any other ways to display this image in a dynamic web page?

Answer (score 0):

The path depends on how your servlet is mapped in web.xml (as I don't see any annotations in your code). The other - but rather discouraged - way is to use data URI. See [I want to retrieve image from mysql database using servlet and show that image along with that user details in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31110939/i-want-to-retrieve-image-from-mysql-database-using-servlet-and-show-that-image-a/31113020#31113020)

Comment: how can I find **data URI** of the image?

Comment: Read the answer in the linked question, and the link. Study. Do your homework.